# Команда set: как реализовать вложенное использование переменных?

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть две строковые переменные:

```
set foo=D:\dir1\dir11\
set bar=D:\dir1\
```

Как исключить строку `bar` из строки `foo`? Ожидаемым результатом является `dir11\`
Выражение `%foo:%bar%=%` не работает.

Подобная синтаксическая проблема возникает и в других конструкциях:

```
set /a foo=1
set bar="text"
echo %bar:~%foo%,-%foo%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Выражение `%foo:%bar%=%` не работает.

Неправда, работает, расширяясь в `%foo:D:\dir1\=%`. Полученный литерал можно вывести во временный BAT-файл и CALL его...

```
@echo off
cls 
set foo=D:\dir1\dir11\
set bar=D:\dir1\
set strtemp=%%foo:%bar%=%%
echo set foo=%strtemp% > %temp%\temp.bat
call %temp%\temp.bat
echo %foo%
```